# How I can divide a file to blocks in java?

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I try make code by java able to read 100 kb from file then divide the file into blocks each block has 256 bit or 32 byte also I want conver each block to binary format or integer format the following is it 
I need any suggest

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadFileExample newclass = new ReadFileExample();
    System.out.println("-----------Wellcome in ECC ENCRYPTION NEW--------");
    File clearmsg = new File("F:/java_projects/clearmsg.txt");
    File ciphermsg = new File("F:/java_projects/ciphermsg.txt");
    byte[] block = new byte[32];        
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(clearmsg);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphermsg);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos);               
        System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
            + fis.available());
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(block);
            fos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. What isn't working? What do you not understand?

Comment: clearmsg.txt this file has 100 kb ok now I need to read 32 byte from this file after that I want  convert this 32 byte is integer format after that print each 32 byte after converted to integer

Comment: That's exactly what you're already doing. What's the question? BTW available() is the number of bytes you can read without blocking, not the total number of bytes in the stream: see the Javadoc. Use File.length() for that.but I don't see that you need it at Ll.

Comment: You want to convert a whole 32 byte into a single integer? Try BigInteger x = new BigInteger(block); Not sure if thats what you're looking for... Note: This may give you ridiculously large numbers.

Comment: Apologized to absent. Thanks for all. Well What is the function that is used with image files, not text. Is there a link illustrated using a Java program.